# Listening to DOM events on jQuery, tryjQuery by codeschool

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jQuery on TryjQuery by codeschool. This is the HTML code applied to my question..

```
<div class="tour" data-daily-price="357">
<h2>Paris, France Tour</h2>
<p>$<span id="total">2,499</span> for <span id="nights-count">7</span> Nights</p>
<p><label for="nights">Number of Nights</label></p>
<p><input type="number" id="nights" value="7"></p>
</div>
```

and This is the answer for jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nights").on("keyup", function() {
     var nights = +$(this).val();
     var dailyPrice = +$(this).closest(".tour").data("daily-price");
     $("#total").text(nights * dailyPrice);
     $("#nights-count").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I'm just wondering if it's possible for me to use
`var nights = +$("#nights-count").text($(this).val());` instead of using this

```
var nights = +$(this).val();    
$("#nights-count").text($(this).val());
```

I'm curious about the relation of that 2 $(this).val();. Are they duplicated in some way?
which is the efficient way to code this?

I appreciate your times and helps.

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

This is some odd jQuery, with a bit of unnecessary code, and a bit of bad practice as well.

First, the `+` before `$(this).val()`. This is the unary plus operator, which converts `$(this).val()` to a number so it can be used in a mathematical operation. This isn't necessary *per se* because it's only used in a multiplication where it would have been converted anyway, but I suppose it isn't a *bad* idea. (The same is true of the other line where the `+` operator is used.)

`$(this).val()`, however, *is* bad code. `this.value` does precisely the same thing and has far, far better performance.

As for your specific question:

```
var nights = +$("#nights-count").text($(this).val());
```

No, you can't do that. That puts the value in `#nights-count` as you want, but `text` returns a jQuery object. You are therefore attempting to convert a jQuery object to a number. This always results in `NaN` (not-a-number).

If I were writing this code, I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nights").on("keyup", function() {
     var nights = +this.value;
     var dailyPrice = +$(this).closest(".tour").data("daily-price");

     $("#total").text(nights * dailyPrice);

     $("#nights-count").text(nights);
    });
});
```

This means we're not doing any unnecessary function calls.